# How to draw on QGraphicScene in real time?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

i'm having trouble with making app like Windows Paint. I wanted to draw on my window while holding mouse button. I know there's MouseMoveEvent but it has really poor refresh rate for me. Because of that i wanted to create my own event. I tried some options and as for now i have something like that:

```
DrawArea::DrawArea(QObject *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent), buttonPressed(false)
{
    mouseEv = new QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseMove);
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setInterval(60);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){ mousePressEvent(mouseEv); });
}

void DrawArea::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
        QPointF pos = event->scenePos();
        qDebug() << pos;
        auto radius = qreal(2);

        auto* ellipse = this->addEllipse(QRect(pos.x()-radius, pos.y()-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius));
        ellipse->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::black),Qt::SolidPattern));
        buttonPressed = true;

        //connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){ updateDraw(event->scenePos()); });
        timer->start();

        event->accept();
}
```

But the problem is that when i hold my mouse button "pos" variable is equal (0,0). Pos is correct as long as i'm only clicking with my mouse button.

Before I also tried something like this:

```
DrawArea::DrawArea(QObject *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent), buttonPressed(false)
{
    mouseEv = new QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseMove);
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setInterval(60);
}

void DrawArea::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{

    if(event->button() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        QPointF pos = event->scenePos();
        qDebug() << pos;
        auto radius = qreal(2);

        auto* ellipse = this->addEllipse(QRect(pos.x()-radius, pos.y()-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius));
        ellipse->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::black),Qt::SolidPattern));
        buttonPressed = true;

        connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){ updateDraw(event->scenePos()); });
        timer->start();
    }
    else event->ignore();
}

void DrawArea::updateDraw(QPointF mousePos)
{
    mouseEv = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseMove, mousePos, Qt::NoButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
    mouseMoveEv(mouseEv);
}

void DrawArea::mouseMoveEv(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPointF pos = event->pos();
    qDebug() << pos;
    auto radius = qreal(20);

    auto* ellipse = this->addEllipse(QRect(pos.x()-radius, pos.y()-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius));
    ellipse->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::black),Qt::SolidPattern));

    event->accept();
}
```

But still that's not working correctly. I'm quite new to Qt, expecially in Qt Graphics View framework so propably (i wish) i'm doing something stupid. I'll be really thankfull for any help.

**bold**edit
i'm posting picture of my app.
[image]

Comment: ***I know there's MouseMoveEvent but it has really poor refresh rate for me*** Have you tested your code in release mode.

Comment: Do not generate events by yourself. Instead, react to the events, generated by the system.

Comment: @drescherjm jest, i've tested that in release mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will have trouble with something similar, here's my implementation:

```
DrawArea::DrawArea(QObject *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent), mRadius(2), mDrawPath{}
{
    drawing = false; // drawing is boolean type attribute
}

void DrawArea::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
       mDrawPath.moveTo(event->scenePos());
       event->accept();
       drawing = true;
    }
    else event->ignore();
}

void DrawArea::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
   if(event->button() & Qt::LeftButton)
   {
     drawing = false;
   }
}

void DrawArea::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{ 
    if(drawing == false){}
    else
    {
        mDrawPath.lineTo(event->scenePos());

        this->clear();
        addPath(mDrawPath);
    }
}
```

It's worth to mention that this->clear() method in mouseMoveEvent method is a must-have. Without that performance will be great on beginning but during process of drawing it'll drop fast because you will constantly adding new paths which is performance killer.

Comment: Did you manage to draw two shapes in a row with this code?

Comment: @schopchanov yeah... but thanks for pointing that out because i'm not sure why. Even funnier is that if i delete parts with mEllipse attribute in mousePressEvent it start working wrong. After second mouse click app shut down. Any ideas why?

Comment: _i'm not sure why_ `->` because of `this->clear();`.

Comment: @scopchanov not really i think. If i commented that out than it works the same. With 3 lines with mEllipse uncommented it works just fine, and if i delete those line (still without this->clear() method) it's not.

Comment: @scopchanov okay, that's make sense i think... to be more precisly it works with `mEllipse = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(...)` line. It has to because mouseMoveEvent needs that. I've checked that and if mEllipse attribute is switched with boolean flag (true if mouse button is pressed) it's working just fine.

Comment: I cannot guess without seeing a mvce. So I propose you the following: you accept/upvote my answer, as it provides a well structured answer to the question _How to draw on QGraphicScene in real time_. Then you post another question with a proper mvce and enough details to make finding a solution possible.

Comment: _Now it's working._ no it is not. The code block to which `mDrawPath.lineTo(pos);` belongs would never be executed.

Comment: My bad, forgot to add one line. Now after edit I added `drawing = true` inside `mousePressEvent` method, so it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

> i'm doing something stupid

To elaborate on this, you have the wrong approach to the task. Neither `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent`, nor `mousePressEvent` are meant to be generated by the user.

### Solution

Do not generate events by yourself. Instead, react to the events, generated by the system:

1. Reimplement `QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent` to create a new graphics item
2. Reimplement `QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent` to modify the newly created graphics item
3. Reimplement `QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent` to confirm the creation, i.e. to let the item remain in the scene, or to delete the item, e.g. on right mouse click

### Example

Here is an example I wrote for you to demonstrate a possible approach to the problem:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QBoxLayout>

class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *m_ellipse;
public:
    explicit GraphicsView(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QGraphicsView(parent),
        m_ellipse(nullptr) {
        setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));
        setSceneRect(0, 0, 1000, 800);
        setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    }

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override {
        QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);

        if (!(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton))
            return;

        m_ellipse = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(-5, -5, 10, 10);
        m_ellipse->setPos(event->pos());
        m_ellipse->setPen(QPen(Qt::red));

        scene()->addItem(m_ellipse);
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override {
        QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);

        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            if (m_ellipse)
                m_ellipse->setPen(QPen(Qt::black));
        } else {
            delete m_ellipse;
        }

        m_ellipse = nullptr;
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override {
        QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(event);

        if (!m_ellipse)
            return;

        QPointF d = 2*(event->pos() - m_ellipse->pos());

        m_ellipse->setRect(-0.5*d.x(), -0.5*d.y(), d.x(), d.y());
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QWidget(parent) {
        (new QVBoxLayout(this))->addWidget(new GraphicsView(this));

        resize(800, 600);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

### Result

The provided example (with a little bit of creativity) produces the following result:

[image: Abstract circles painting]

Comment: thanks for answer, it looks really helpfull. After work i'll try to implement your approach.

Comment: i've edit my previous post so you can see what currently i have. I've managed to do that with moveEvent, but i wanted to make it solid (without spaces between each point that occurs when i move my mouse too fast). I thought that with my own event and timer i may achieve that, but i;m not sure now. Maybe it's better to use QGraphicPathItem, and make connection between those points by my own?

Comment: @Tojmak, I have given you the right approach to the problem. Run the code, study how it works, play with it, and finally adapt it to suite your own needs. If you are looking for a no-brainer, I doubt someone would provide something like this for you.

Comment: i'm not. But looking on your idea gives me feeling that i've made something very similar. Maybe i'm not catching something, if that's the true, than sorry for my impatience and i will study that more carefully. But for now it's really looking to me like basic idea to use mouseMoveEvent. I wrote previously that i'v tried that. 3 pointers that you mentioned is exactly what i've implemented in first place. I'm only looking for ideas. Well... if you;re sure that it should help me than again - sorry for impetience and i will try to look more on what you wrote

Comment: @Tojmak, you are generating the events yourself. This is very different.

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear. I mentioned at the beginning that i know that mouseMoveEvent exists and it's not covering my problem entirely. By that i mean that i've tried that idea. I've only not posted that here because i made it work like it should and it was clear for me that i've cannot achieve what i wanted with that approach. Because of that, and because you mentioned that my own event is propably not the best idea, later i asked if QGraphicPathItem may solve my problem. I've currently working with that, and i'm thinking that may work

Comment: @Tojmak, _I know there's MouseMoveEvent but it has really poor refresh rate for me._ Does the example I have provided perform poorly on your machine?

Comment: well... maybe saying that's poorly is too much. It looks exactly like in the image that i'm showing above (there's no really metters if i use your or mine implementation - it's nearly the same). I may expect too much of that. The spaces between drew circles are showing after nearly instant moving my mouse.

Comment: Yeah, i've managed to do what i wanted. The idea is to use QPainterPath. Thanks for your support